# Getting jsonEncode to encode DateTime

Tags: json, dart

New to Dart and find it weird that `jsonEncode` (from `convert` package) is refusing to play well with `DateTime`, I'm having to turn all instances of `DateTime` to a `String` using the `.toIso8601String()`, is there a way to avoid doing this over and over manually?